# Поменять тригер в шаблоне XAML ("наследование шаблонов")

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я создал стиль для кнопок `DefaultButton`, в котором сделал сеттер для шаблона, и внутри шаблона сделал несколько тригеров, чтобы кнопка меняла фон:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="DefaultButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />            
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Margin="5" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD6D6D6"/> 
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFA5A5A5"/> 
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBABABA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

После этого я захотел точно такой же стиль, но только что бы поменять два тригера, так, чтобы фон при наведении был другим. Я могу с лёгкостью унаследовать стиль с помощью `BaseOn="StaticResource DefaultButton"` и изменить сеттер для шаблона.

Получился вот такой 2й стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="OperationButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Margin="5" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF89E8E6"/> <!-- первое отличие --!>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF94F3F2"/> <!-- второе отличие --!>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBABABA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Получилось 90% повторяющегося кода из-за отсутсвия наследования для шаблонов. Можно ли как-то этого избежать и писать 2 строчке вместо копирования 20ти?

Comment: Используйте `Style.Triggers` вместо `ControlTemplate.Triggers` или комбинируйте

Comment: А вообще можете создать юзерконтрол-кнопку, в который натыкать свойств, хранящих все нужные цвета. А в шаблоне этой кнопки просто прибиндиться к ним. Тогда в окне можно будет либо явно указывать цвета в разметке кнопки, либо через стили, легко.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подмена данных в стилях легко достигается при помощи следующего трюка. В триггере данные не хардкодируем, а берём из ресурсов стиля, а в новом стиле переопределяем их. Получается вот что:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="DefaultButton">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush">#FFD6D6D6</SolidColorBrush>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" >
                ...
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ...
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="OperationButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButton}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- тут переопределяем цвета -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverBrush">#FF89E8E6</SolidColorBrush>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```